# JProfiler hangs with "waiting for a JProfiler GUI to connect" message

Tags: java, profiling, jprofiler

I am trying to run JProfiler on win64 on Tomcat and Oracle Weblogic. After I run the wizard, it hangs at line

"waiting for a JProfiler GUI to connect"

On the other hand, the GUI is waiting to connect with profiled jvm on the default port, but there it hangs.

I can still run JProfiler from eclipse with Tomcat. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Did you find any workaround for this?? Please share if any.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check firewall issues. Sounds like the firewall is preventing the sockets from connecting.